# apt-get exits bash script after installing packages

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, scripts

I have read the answers in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372810/how-to-prevent-script-not-to-stop-after-apt-get) but it doesn't seem to work for my problem.

I am executing a bash script via stdin from wget:

```
wget -O - http://serverip/subfolder/script | sudo bash
```

I've tried using `apt-get -y --force-yes install <packages..> || true`, but it still exits the script if the one of the listed is installed by apt-get.

It doesn't exit the script if all the listed packages are already installed.

The same thing happens if I have a `apt-get upgrade` and it installs package(s).  It will exit the script.

I have another set of scripts, that seems to work.  In that scenario, the install script is just a stub, that downloads, runs the script via `bash <scriptname>` then deletes the script.  The script itself will elevate its privilege by sudoing itself.  `apt-get` works as expected here.

Any insight as to how to prevent `apt-get` from terminating the script would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wish people would stop doing: `wget | bash`. It's just silly, and has unintended effects like the one here. You have bash, so make use of its features. In particular, process substitution:

```
bash <(wget -O - http://serverip/subfolder/script)
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably just need to stop `apt-get` from greedily reading the standard input. Do this by redirecting stdin to `/dev/null`, a file that returns eof to reads. Eg:

```
apt-get -y --force-yes install ... </dev/null
```